# What to do with the gameserver tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

Recent activity brought to my attention that there is a [gameserver](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/gameserver) tag, and a significant fraction of the questions under that tag looks like they are off-topic due to being hobbyist questions rather than professional system administration.

We should acknowledge that there is such a thing as professional game server administrators, gaming is a big business after all. And those administrators should consider themselves as welcome on this site as any other system administrators.

However I expect most of those will be administrating games developed in house, and as such the questions they would ask on this site are unlikely to be about their game server per se, but rather about the platform it is built on.

This leaves only a very narrow scope of on-topic questions likely to use the [gameserver](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/gameserver) tag, many of which are likely better suited on [Game Development](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/).

Is there a sufficient amount of on-topic questions to keep the tag? Or should it be marked off-topic?

Comment: Any Server Fault users who administrate game servers for a living are obviously very welcome to comment or answer here.

Comment: Unrelated to the issue, but if in the end it's on-topic, I feel like the tag deserves a rename to [tag:game-server]...

Answer (score 8):

I agree with your reasoning and I think the best thing we could do is to edit the tag wiki to make it clear that only game servers in a business context are valid here. This will likely be a very small set of questions but I don't think we should exclude it in general.

I just did that.